# Accordion doesn't collapse properly when having multiple accordions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

> TL;DR How can I approach this situation when you have one accordion that allows multiple items from a model?

I have a Rails application that powers Twitter Bootstrap, so I was trying to setup several accordion panels using ERB to get some dynamic content from a model. Here is my application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Most importantly, I want to have a accordion that renders each one individually. Here is my index.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Showing all <%= @courses.count %> courses</h1>

  <% if @courses.present? %>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
      <%= link_to course.name, course_path(course) %>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <%= link_to course.name, '#collapseOne', 'role' => 'button', data: {toggle: 'collapse', parent: '#accordion' } %>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <%= render partial: 'courses/show', id: course %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <p>You should create a course!</p>
  <% end %>

  <br><br>
  <%= link_to "New Course", new_course_path %>
</div>
```

It only lets me collapse the first accordion, not the others. How can I handle this problem with accordion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop you use the same element id `id="accordion"` for all of your panel groups:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
```

You should assign dynamic id per iteration.

```
<% @courses.each_with_index do |course, index| %>
  <%= link_to course.name, course_path(course) %>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-<%= index %>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <%# Snipped for brevity %>
```

Comment: I am kinda confused by this. Should I either put a `id="<%= some_helper here %>"` or something related to that?

Comment: @RodrigoArgumedo You can use something like the code I just added to my answer.